# Where is the RUNNING_PID file written in Play application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to understand where the RUNNING_PID file is written in Play application. I know the location where it is written. I wanted to understand at what point when you start the application is the RUNNING_PID file written? Is it written by the JVM process which the shell script starts or by the shell script which starts the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's written by the JVM process which the shell script starts:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala#L222

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to delete the RUNNING_PID file from within the JVM process when you kill the JVM process i.e. basically do a "kill -9 pid" ?

Comment: kill -9 tells the operating system to kill the process without giving the process any chance to intercept or handle the kill signal.  So no, it's not possible to do any clean up from within any process when you kill -9 it.  But if you send a SIGTERM (kill -15, or just straight kill), then Play will clean up after itself.  The whole point of SIGKILL is when a program is refusing to exit (maybe due to a bug or deadlock in the clean up code), so it bypasses any clean up code.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, i can't post a comment yet, so my answer goes here. In order to delete the process based on the pid file, you can follow this script:

`pid=`cat ${PATH_TO}/RUNNING_PID
`kill $pid`

Comment: I don't want to delete the process based on the PID. I basically want to delete the RUNNING_PID file from the JVM process when when the process is being killed.